# Unable to view IIS Current Requests

Tags: iis

I installed all Health and Diagnostics. Current Requests page is still blank.
I am only running PHP so only CGI is installed for Applications. Does this not work for PHP on IIS? Under Management Tools I only have IIS Management Console installed. Not checked are: IIS 6 Management Compatibility, IIS Management Scripts and tools, Management Service. I'm running IIS 10.0.20348.1

Update:
One time I saw a .php program in the Current requests. It was a program I executed several minutes ago. As I enter new web requests from different .php programs, nothing shows up on Current Requests in real-time. I pressed Show All and the page went blank. As I enter new web requests, the page remains blank. The server is a virtual server on Amazon Web Services.

I see this sometimes if I keep pressing the Show All button; otherwise, the page remains blank:
[image: Requests]